# O que é isso? private List<Map<String, Object>> gastos;

Tags: java

Uma lista de mapas? É sério fiquei assustada com isso. Nunca vi isso na minha vida...

```
private List<Map<String, Object>> listarGastos() {
  gastos = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
  Map<String, Object> item = new HashMap<String, Object>();
 item.put("data", "04/02/2012");
 item.put("descricao", "Diária Hotel");
 item.put("valor", "R$ 260,00");
 item.put("categoria", R.color.categoria_hospedagem);
 gastos.add(item);

   return gastos;
 }
}
```

Comment: è isso mesmo uma lista de mapas...

Comment: Esse método poderia muito bem retornar apenas o `Map` criado, já que o que ele está criando é uma lista com um único elemento, e portanto não há muito sentido de que seja uma lista para começar. Gostaria de saber onde esse método é utilizado para entender se há sentido em isso ser uma lista de mapas ou se deveria ser outra coisa. Onde esse método é utilizado?

Comment: A resposta lhe foi útil? Não esqueça de marcar o ✅ para que possa ser utilizada caso alguém tenha uma dúvida similar!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim, é uma lista de mapas. Ela permite que você insira um conjunto de chaves e valores formando uma estrutura como a do seu exemplo:

```
[
  {"data": "04/02/2012"},
  {"descricao": "Diária Hotel"},
  {"valor": "R$ 260,00"},
  {"categoria": R.color.categoria_hospedagem}
]
```

No caso de você saber quais são os atributos colocados no `Map` é mais efetivo criar um objeto no formato esperado. Torna o código mais legível e mais fácil de ser trabalhado.

Seria melhor representado por:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;

public class Item {

  private LocalDate data;
  private String descricao;
  private double valor;
  private String categoria;

  public LocalDate getData() {
    return data;
  }

  public void setData(LocalDate data) {
    this.data = data;
  }

  public String getDescricao() {
    return descricao;
  }

  public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
    this.descricao = descricao;
  }

  public double getValor() {
    return valor;
  }

  public void setValor(double valor) {
    this.valor = valor;
  }

  public String getCategoria() {
    return categoria;
  }

  public void setCategoria(String categoria) {
    this.categoria = categoria;
  }
}
```

E a utilização seria:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
List<Item> gastos = new ArrayList<>();
Item item = new Item();

item.setData(LocalDate.parse("04/02/2012", formatter));
item.setDescricao("Diária Hotel");
item.setValor(260.00);
item.setCategoria(R.color.categoria_hospedagem);
gastos.add(item);
```